# error APPX0702: Payload file ....\Projects\WRC1\Debug\WRC1\WRC1\BlankPage1.xaml' does not exist

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I have added a blank page in a windows runtime component dll and then added its reference to a app(app1) project.
While comipling the app1, I am somehow getting the error:

> error APPX0702: Payload file 'c:\Users\documents\visual
>   studio 2012\Projects\WRC1\Debug\WRC1\WRC1\BlankPage1.xaml' does not
>   exist

The page has been by default created at
`....\Projects\WRC1\WRC1\Debug\`        while it is incorrectly searching @
`.....\Projects\WRC1\Debug\WRC1\WRC1\`

Can someone please point me to what might be causing this or could there be some config issue ?